# VBA: Run-time error '424' with AutoFilter

Tags: vba, autofilter

I have searched the forum but haven't found an answer for my question.

Sub delMakro()

Dim rngAutoFill As Range

Set rngAutoFill = Range("A1:Z1")

```
rngAutoFill.Select
rngAutoFill.AutoFilter = True
```

End Sub

I get Run-time error '424' but don't understand why

Comment: Have you written this in some vbs file or in the code behind of sheet/workbook ? Its a good practice to refer range along with workbook and sheet name so that code can be reused.

Comment: In the code behind. You mean the VBA-Editor? (Alt+F11)

Comment: I think you call the range of cells you want to fill but didn't call the worksheet and workbook you are referring to.

Comment: I meant Excel's developer editor where you can write code

Comment: Yes exactly. Thats the same one

Answer (score 0):

[Autofilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) method can return a (`Variant`) value but it can't be *assigned* a value like you're trying to do with `rngAutoFill.AutoFilter = True`

If you just want to toggle the display of the drop-down arrows in the relevant range, then use

```
rngAutoFill.AutoFilter '<-- if dropdown arrows were off, it turns them on and viceversa
```

If you want to make drop-down arrows appear in the 1st field of your range

```
rngAutoFill.AutoFilter field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=True
```

If you want to make drop-down arrows appear in the 2nd and 4th field of your range

```
rngAutoFill.AutoFilter field:=Array(2,4), VisibleDropDown:=True
```

Comment: @Petter__, did this help you?